# redhawk ide chalkboard palette is empty

Tags: redhawksdr

I made an installation of the RedHawk framework and IDE on a Linux Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit system). It seems to run correctly but I don't see any Component (like sigGen or hardLimit) in the Chalkboard palette. My $SDRROOT/dom/components dir is empty. How can I correct this? How can I find and install available Components? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*Appendix F Installing REDHAWK on Ubuntu* of the PDF REDHAWK Manual Version 1.10.0 only gives instructions for downloading and building the sources necessary for the base system (page 390).  To install the components used in the manual's IDE Quickstart, you need to clone the `basic-components` git repository and copy it into the `$SDRROOT/dom/components` folder.

From the `git` directory used in section *F.3 Building REDHAWK*, run the following in the shell:

```
git clone https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/basic-components
```

Go into each sub-directory of `basic-components/` (e.g., `SigGen/`) and run the build script:

```
./build.sh
```

Once you have build the components, go back up to the `git` directory and run:

```
cp -r basic-components/ $SDRROOT/dom/components/
```

The basic REDHAWK components (`SigGen`, `HardLimit`, etc.) should now appear in the Palette the next time you start the REDHAWK IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The components are part of the core framework tarball. For the Redhawk 1.9.0, the rpm is named redhawk-basic-components-1.9.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm. Check the installation instructions (http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch2.html#x4-100002.4) for more info.

Comment: Note that the OP installed this on an Ubuntu machine, and following the instructions on the Redhawk site for Ubuntu renders the components dir empty. The question is still valid.